# Assign a value for a text cell

Tags: excel

is it possible to assign a value for a cell that contains text?

To illustrate a lit bit let´s suppose that Barcelona has 8 Titles, Real Madrid 8, Bayern Munchen 5, Arsenal 7

So every time I see a cell that contains "Barcelona" it is equal to 8 and "Arsenal" equals to 7. Meaning that if sum the cell containing "Barcelona" and "Arsenal", the output will be 15. Is it possible to make something like this without having to use another table with those established values?

Thank you!!!

Comment: is the number always last?

Comment: Vlookup() or choose() come to mind.

Comment: Possible? Yes. How simple it is will depend on your layout. Not really sure why this would be needed, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work, but you have to type it out every time:

```
=SWITCH(A1,"Barcelona",8,"Arsenal",7,"Real Madrid",8,"Bayern Munchen","5")
```

It sounds like what you want is a defined name. Just go to the formulas ribbon and click define name. Then Type in the name of the Team and Enter the constant under the refers to box.
[image]

Now you'll be able to use Arsenal in your formulas and it will result in 7.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Bryan